# how to ARRAY specific cells based on rules?

Tags: filter, google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

is there a (maybe a one (?) formula)-way how to pick all green cells (but only those which has numbers and excluding 0) in a row  and put/list them in an array to that coresponding row ??

example: in cell `AO1` there will be formula that will list these results:

> AO1 = 647
>
> AP1 = 2806
>
> AQ1 = 15490
>
> AR1 = 32105
>
> AS1 = 33808

[image]

something like array of constants but constant will be a cell reference... I can only think of a hard way to doing it like make a table/grid of all green cells and then array them, but not sure how could I exlude things from arraying (things like: skip empty cell and skip cell that is "<1" )

**edit:** in another words: **cell AO1:** `=arrayformula({$p$1;$r$1;$t$1;$v$1;$x$1;$z$1;$ab$1;$ad$1;$af$1;$ah$1;$aj$1;$al$1};and dont array empty and "<1" cells)`

Comment: Filter? https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=fr

Comment: @LioraHaydont filter helped but I needed to make extra step by setting up a 2nd table (next to my existing table) with only my green cells

Comment: Can you show the expected result and why filter doesn't help? I'm not sure I understand what you mean

Comment: the width/height of your table is always the same?

Comment: @LioraHaydont yes. also all green cells are fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the row are fixed could simply use [filter](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197) on all the rows

like this : *(I used the range you give in your question)*

```
=FILTER(
    {$p$1;$r$1;$t$1;$v$1;$x$1;$z$1;$ab$1;$ad$1;$af$1;$ah$1;$aj$1;$al$1};
    {$p$1;$r$1;$t$1;$v$1;$x$1;$z$1;$ab$1;$ad$1;$af$1;$ah$1;$aj$1;$al$1}>0)
```

And for the K and the unique you can add them like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(FILTER(
{$p$1;$r$1;$t$1;$v$1;$x$1;$z$1;$ab$1;$ad$1;$af$1;$ah$1;$aj$1;$al$1};
{$p$1;$r$1;$t$1;$v$1;$x$1;$z$1;$ab$1;$ad$1;$af$1;$ah$1;$aj$1;$al$1}>0))&" K")
```